# Interview Question: Longest Prefix That Contains An Equal Number Of Two Integers

Tags: c, algorithm

I attempted to solve the following question in an online assessment for a technical interview, and failed.  I have been thinking about the problem for a while now, and can't seem to find an answer that satisfies me:

You are looking for the longest leading fragment (prefix) of an array A in which there is an equal number of occurrences of X, and Y, where X and Y are integers.

For example, where X=7 and Y=42, the longest prefix where A=[6, 42, 11, 7, 1, 42] would be 4, because A[0]-A[4] contain the same number of X and Y.

Another example, X=6 and Y=13.
A=[13,13,1,6].  The function should return -1, because there is no prefix.

X=100, Y=63, and A=[100,63,1,6,2,13] should return 5.

My attempt at an answer in C:

```
int solution(int X, int Y, int A[], int N){
  int result=-1;
  int nX=0; //number of occurrences of X
  int nY=0; //number of occurrences of Y
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){//loop through the input array
    if(A[i]==X)//occurrence of X
      nX += 1;

    /*
    EDGE CASE BELOW: this should have been an if 
    statement, because X and Y could be the same 
    number.  I know I missed this in the assessment, 
    but believe there is another issue, because I 
    failed almost all the test cases generated by the 
    assessment. 
    */
    else if(A[i]==Y)//occurrence of Y 
      nY += 1;
    if((nX!=0)&& (nX==nY))//same number of X and Y 
    //and there is at least one occurence of each
      result=i;//longest prefix is the index
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to generate a test case myself that failed, and the failure test cases are hidden on the assessment. Thus I can't provide much information that would be helpful.

I do know, that every time I failed, my program returned a -1 instead of the correct answer.

If any of you can see something wrong just through thinking through it, I would love to see what I am missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you supposed to return the length of the longest prefix, or the index of the last element of the longest prefix?

Comment: The index of the last element of the longest prefix.  There wording could have been clearer, which is why I included the example cases in my question.

Comment: In addition to what ruakh said, you can solve the problem with a single counter. `int n=0; for (i=0;i<N;i++){ if(A[i]==X) n++; if (A[i]==Y) n--; if (n==0) result=i; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've accurately described the requirements, then they don't specify an equal *positive* number of occurrences of *X* and *Y*. Zero is valid.

So this:

```
    if((nX!=0)&& (nX==nY))//same number of X and Y 
    //and there is at least one occurence of each
      result=i;//longest prefix is the index
    }
```

should be this:

```
    if(nX==nY)//same number of X and Y 
      result=i;//longest prefix is the index
    }
```

without the check for `nX!=0`. So if *X* doesn't appear in the array and/or *Y* doesn't appear in the array, your code returns −1 unnecessarily.

Additionally, the requirements don't seem to guarantee that *X* and *Y* are distinct; if they're not, then your code returns −1, but according to a literal reading of the requirements, the answer would be *N*−1.

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually thought about that as well.  It was an ambiguity that I would have just asked the interviewer were it in person.  I think you are correct, as they did not say that it couldn't be that.

Comment: Also what does your last sentence mean?

Comment: @Joshua: My last sentence means that if (for example) X = Y = 12 and the array is [12, 12, 12], then the correct answer is 2 but your code returns −1. (To fix that, change `else if(A[i]==Y)` to `if(A[i]==Y)`.)

Comment: Gotcha,  Yes I included a comment about that in my code.  I know I messed up there.

Comment: @Joshua: Oh, ha, yes, so you did. Such a big comment. Dunno how I missed it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was really bothering me, and I appreciate the help!  I went ahead and gave you best answer.

Answer (score 4):

After seeing your requirements and answers there is another change required to your code @Joshua.

The answer from @ruakh is also right but need one more change to handle other test cases.

You have to replace the "else if" condition to "if" condition for the occurrence of Y as shown in below code:

```
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    if(A[i]==X)
      nX += 1;
    if(A[i]==Y)  //occurrence of Y 
      nY += 1;
```

Because, if "X" and "Y" have the same values and only "nX" will be counted, and "nY" is ignored with the "else if" condition. To tackle this situation you have to replace the "else if" condition with the "if" condition.

Sample: X=42, Y=42, and A=[42,63,42,6,2,13]

then with my condition, the above sample is handled perfectly.

I hope my answer solved or added more accuracy to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For starters never do any assignments in an interview. Interview is not an exam. It is a conversation of two equal participants. Ignore all firms that try to manipulate you and your time such a way.

Secondly, this function declaration

```
int solution(int X, int Y, int A[], int N);
```

is a declaration of a beginner.

First of all do not use upper case letters to name parameters.

Secondly the size of the array shall have the type size_t as and the return type of the function.

Thirdly the array should be the first parameter of the function and shall have the qualifier const.

Fourthly, declare variables in the smallest scope where they are used.

The function can be declared as it is shown in the demonstrative program. The function returns 0 if there is no such a prefix. You can change the return value either to the size of the array if there is no the prefix ot to ( size_t ) -1 as you like.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t largest_balanced_seq( const int a[], size_t n, int x, int y )
{
    size_t last_index = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0, x_count = 0, y_count = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        x_count += a[i] == x;
        y_count += a[i] == y;

        if ( x_count != 0 && x_count == y_count )
        {
            last_index = i;
        }
    }

    return last_index;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 6, 42, 11, 7, 1, 42 };

    printf( "%zu\n", largest_balanced_seq( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), 7, 42 ) );

    int b[] = { 100, 63, 1, 6, 2, 13 };

    printf( "%zu\n", largest_balanced_seq( b, sizeof( b ) / sizeof( *b ), 100, 63 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4
5
```

Take into account that it is much better when the function returns the length of the sub-sequence, that is when it specifiers a range like `[0, N)`. For example such an approach is used throughout C++. So who gave you this assignment is not a very high qualified.:)

Comment: "_never do any assignments in an interview_": I get the point but when you're looking for a first job, well.. I'm not sure you really have a choice!

Comment: @kebs For the first work, general intellectual development is important not the knowledge of a language or of some algorithm.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for the reply. Why did you use size_t?

Comment: @Joshua Because it is the type that is used by the operator sizeof and as the size of an array. The type int can be small to fit the size of an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(X, Y, A):

    N = len(A)
    result = -1
    nX = 0
    nY = 0

    for i in range(N):
        if A[i] == X:
            nX += 1
        if A[i] == Y:
            nY += 1
        if nX == nY:
            result = i
            if (X == Y and nX != 0):
                break

    return result

print( solution(7, 42, [6, 42, 11, 7, 1, 42]) )
print( solution(6, 13, [13, 13, 1, 6]) )
print( solution(100, 63, [100, 63, 1, 6, 2, 13]) )
print( solution(1, 1, [1]) )
print( solution(1, 1, [1, 1, 1]) )
print( solution(1, 1, [1, 2, 1]) )
print( solution(1, 1, [2, 2, 1]) )
print( solution(1, 1, [2, 1, 2]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int solution(int X, int Y, int A[], int N){
  int result=-1;
  int nX=0; //number of occurrences of X
  int nY=0; //number of occurrences of Y
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){//loop through the input array
    if(A[i]==X)//occurrence of X
      nX += 1;

    /*
    EDGE CASE BELOW: this should have been an if 
    statement, because X and Y could be the same 
    number.  I know I missed this in the assessment, 
    but believe there is another issue, because I 
    failed almost all the test cases generated by the 
    assessment. 
    */
    else if(A[i]==Y)//occurrence of Y 
      nY += 1;
    if((nX!=0)&& (nX==nY))//same number of X and Y 
    //and there is at least one occurence of each
      result=i;//longest prefix is the index
    if (X==Y)
      result =i;
    }---this two lines of code is needed for the code correction
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(X, Y, A):

    N = len(A)
    result = -1
    nX = 0
    nY = 0

    for i in range(N):
        if X==Y:
            if A[i]==X:
                nX += 1
            if nX%2==0:
                result=i
        else:
            if A[i] == X:
                nX += 1
            elif A[i] == Y:
                nY += 1
            if nX == nY:
                result = i
    return result

print( solution(7, 42, [6, 42, 11, 7, 1, 42]))

print( solution(6, 13, [13, 13, 1, 6]) )

print( solution(100, 63, [100, 63, 1, 6, 2, 13]) )

print( solution(1, 1, [1]) )

print( solution(1, 1, [1, 1, 1]) )
```

utput:

```
4
-1
5
-1
1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
int solution(int X, int Y, int[] A) {
    int N = A.length;
    int result = -1;
    int nX = 0;
    int nY = 0;

    if (X != Y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (A[i] == X)
                nX += 1;
            else if (A[i] == Y)
                nY += 1;
            if (nX == nY)
                result = i;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (A[i] == X){
                nX += 1;
                if(nX % 2 == 1 && nX > 1)
                    result = i - 1;
            }
        }
        if (nX % 2 == 0)
            result = N - 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code shouldn't be the only piece of information provided in an answer. Please provide more information in your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.